# Repeating Section for item in a List - where is the data stored?

Tags: list, repeating-table

I have developed a form for displaying data in a SP List.

I have added a `repeating section` on the form, and it will save the data. It doesn't save to the list, which makes sense, but where does SP save this data? Is it possible to expose this data to allow me to sort/filter lists based on the data within these repeating sections?